# Div horizontal scroll with jQuery animate is not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have put my problem in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ze7zkbu/4/). I have seen other similar question but it didn't work out quite well. It would be great if you guys point what is the mistake i am making here. I have tried passing duration like these

```
{ "duration": 400, "easing": "linear" }
```

as well as directly including the duration. `400`

```
carousel.finish().animate({
    left : '-='+itemWidth
},'linear', function(){

   lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
   lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
   lastItem.css('left', ((carouselChild.length-1)*(itemWidth))+(clickCount*itemWidth));
            });
```

Comment: Put quotes around 400

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried `speed:` property? not sure what method those properties are applied to...

Comment: I want to achieve something like this http://jsfiddle.net/rGLsG/478/. I see my code is right but not sure what is causing the issue